# During the final battle, why did just one Smith fight with Neo?

Tags: the-matrix, agent-smith

In the final battle between Smith and Neo, we can see almost all Smith clones just watching the fight. Why didn't the rest of them join, wouldn't that make them stronger? Also, could it matter which copy of Agent Smith actually took part in this fight?

Comment: This makes me think of the [one electron idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe)

Comment: Since you asked, I feel like it's worth pointing out that they tried the Wall of Agents attack before and it didn't work.  They'd just get in the way of Oracle Smith who can fly now, because of course that's how that works.

Answer (score 10):

Smith is overconfident. In particular, the Smith that fights Neo is the Smith that was created by assimilating the Oracle, and the Smith/Oracle hybrid has foreseen that it only takes him alone to beat Neo.

> Smith/Oracle: Mr. Anderson, welcome back. We missed you. You like what
> I’ve done with the place?
>
> Neo: It ends tonight.
>
> Smith/Oracle: I know
> it does – I’ve seen it. That’s why the rest of me is just going to
> enjoy the show – we already know that I’m the one that beats you.

Unfortunately for Smith, he doesn't understand Neo's choice of self-sacrifice at the end, and, I'd argue, he doesn't really understand his own choices. As the Oracle said, no one can see past choices they don't understand, so Smith didn't understand the consequences of his and Neo's actions.

Deus Ex Machina (the baby-faced computer that Neo spoke to) can take out all the Smiths based on Neo being assimilated by one of them, so I doubt whether it would matter which Smith took part in the fight from that perspective. From a story aspect, the Smith/Oracle hybrid is the one with the power of foresight. That, combined with what looks like the Oracle's subconscious influence on Smith before and after the fight, makes him the perfect one to decide to fight Neo.

Answer (score -1):

Since both of them are nothing but a code, the other copies of Smith will work equally. There was no use of to fight together for them. If one of them are corrupted by another code, which is Neo, the whole of the other copies of Smith will become blunt, as shown.